# How to patch something with diff output?

Tags: diff, patch

I want to apply the below changes to some code that someone has written and provided a `diff` output from. Is there a way given only the output below I can easily create a patch and apply it, or (as it's only a few lines) should I just stick with making the changes by hand?

Even excluding the example below, if this was a large `diff` output then I would really want to know if given only this, can I feed this into `patch` or similar?

```
diff -r -c ganeti-2.5.1_orig/lib//constants.py
ganeti-2.5.1/lib//constants.py
*** ganeti-2.5.1_orig/lib//constants.py 2012-05-11 16:55:13.000000000 +0400
--- ganeti-2.5.1/lib//constants.py      2012-06-28 13:30:41.000000000 +0400
***************
*** 698,703 ****
--- 698,704 ----
  HV_KVM_USE_CHROOT = "use_chroot"
  HV_CPU_MASK = "cpu_mask"
  HV_MEM_PATH = "mem_path"
+ HV_PASSTHROUGH = "pci_pass"
  HV_BLOCKDEV_PREFIX = "blockdev_prefix"
  HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR = "reboot_behavior"

***************
*** 743,748 ****
--- 744,750 ----
    HV_KVM_USE_CHROOT: VTYPE_BOOL,
    HV_CPU_MASK: VTYPE_STRING,
    HV_MEM_PATH: VTYPE_STRING,
+   HV_PASSTHROUGH: VTYPE_STRING,
    HV_BLOCKDEV_PREFIX: VTYPE_STRING,
    HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR: VTYPE_STRING,
    }
***************
*** 1280,1285 ****
--- 1282,1288 ----
      HV_MIGRATION_MODE: HT_MIGRATION_NONLIVE,
      HV_USE_LOCALTIME: False,
      HV_BLOCKDEV_PREFIX: "hd",
+     HV_PASSTHROUGH: "",
      HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR: INSTANCE_REBOOT_ALLOWED,
      },
    HT_KVM: {
diff -r -c ganeti-2.5.1_orig/lib//hypervisor/hv_xen.py
ganeti-2.5.1/lib//hypervisor/hv_xen.py
*** ganeti-2.5.1_orig/lib//hypervisor/hv_xen.py 2012-05-11
16:55:13.000000000 +0400
--- ganeti-2.5.1/lib//hypervisor/hv_xen.py      2012-06-28
13:30:43.000000000 +0400
***************
*** 579,585 ****
      constants.HV_USE_LOCALTIME: hv_base.NO_CHECK,
      # TODO: Add a check for the blockdev prefix (matching [a-z:] or
similar).
      constants.HV_BLOCKDEV_PREFIX: hv_base.NO_CHECK,
!     constants.HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR:
        hv_base.ParamInSet(True, constants.REBOOT_BEHAVIORS)
      }

--- 579,587 ----
      constants.HV_USE_LOCALTIME: hv_base.NO_CHECK,
      # TODO: Add a check for the blockdev prefix (matching [a-z:] or
similar).
      constants.HV_BLOCKDEV_PREFIX: hv_base.NO_CHECK,
! #passthrough pci
!     constants.HV_PASSTHROUGH:  hv_base.NO_CHECK,
!    constants.HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR:
        hv_base.ParamInSet(True, constants.REBOOT_BEHAVIORS)
      }

***************
*** 671,677 ****
        disk_data.append(iso)

      config.write("disk = [%s]\n" % (",".join(disk_data)))
!
      config.write("on_poweroff = 'destroy'\n")
      if hvp[constants.HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR] ==
constants.INSTANCE_REBOOT_ALLOWED:
        config.write("on_reboot = 'restart'\n")
--- 673,684 ----
        disk_data.append(iso)

      config.write("disk = [%s]\n" % (",".join(disk_data)))
!     # this is pci pass
!     pci_pass = hvp[constants.HV_PASSTHROUGH]
!     if pci_pass:
!        pci_pass_arr = []
!        pci_pass_arr = pci_pass.split("/")
!        config.write("pci = %s \n" % pci_pass_arr)
      config.write("on_poweroff = 'destroy'\n")
      if hvp[constants.HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR] ==
constants.INSTANCE_REBOOT_ALLOWED:
        config.write("on_reboot = 'restart'\n")
diff -r -c ganeti-2.5.1_orig/lib//query.py ganeti-2.5.1/lib//query.py
*** ganeti-2.5.1_orig/lib//query.py     2012-05-11 16:55:13.000000000 +0400
--- ganeti-2.5.1/lib//query.py  2012-06-28 13:30:43.000000000 +0400
***************
*** 1638,1643 ****
--- 1638,1644 ----
      constants.HV_NIC_TYPE: "NIC_type",
      constants.HV_PAE: "PAE",
      constants.HV_VNC_BIND_ADDRESS: "VNC_bind_address",
+     constants.HV_PASSTHROUGH: "pci_pass",
      }

    fields = [
```

Comment: Yes, that’s how [diff/patch](http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html) works. You find the [differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) so that you only need to store those instead of the whole file, then you can [patch](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=patch) a file automatically. The file above *is* the patch, you don’t need to create it. You apply it to the existing file (assuming the existing file is from the immediately previous version from the patch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `patch` for applying this diff to a file. Save it as `foo.diff` and apply it like this:

```
patch < foo.diff
```

Comment: Ah yes I see now, sorry for my late reply. It took me a while to test this out. I see now that `patch` takes direct `diff` output as input. I didn't realise it would understand the formatting of `diff` directly and though it may have to be formatted correctly for `patch`. Thanks!